# English letters is in reverse order(Inside wkwebview) for arabic app

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

hi when i update my OS to version 14,
i've seen problem in webview that english letters is in reverse order on my arabic app.

my app localization is set to:

```
Localization native development region = ar
```

and using below code to load webview:

```
let webURL = "https://davidwalsh.name/demo/iphone-camera.php"
 webView?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: webURL)!))
```

here is picture to my problem
[image]

i upload my project on github to test it on Xcode 12:
[Github Link](https://github.com/rezamagnet/TestWebView)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @DávidPásztor my question dosen't have any special code just load website, but i editi it to have more details

Comment: Seems like an Xcode 12 bug.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yeah i think so,
after update my Xcode to 12 and update my iOS to 14 this happend to me

Comment: Cool, file a bug report with Apple.