# wkWebview dropdown popover Mirror text ios issue in arbic language

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios15

We are facing this issue when running iOS 15 later. Changing the language to Arabic causes this issue in WKWebView.Changing application language english to arbic causing this issue.We are loading the url in the wkwebview and dropdown popover text got reversed for arbic language.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE53s.jpg)

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006782/english-letters-is-in-reverse-orderinside-wkwebview-for-arabic-app

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: Set the `"semanticContentAttribute"` property of your `WKWebView` instance to `".forceLeftToRight"`.

Comment: already it has been set .

Comment: I think it may be caused by after updating your iOS because same situation also happen to my friends also.if its not working by **semanticContentAttribute** then set **accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors** property of your **WKWebView** instance to **true**. may be it will help. @iosDev

Comment: its not working. is it os issue?VishnuMangalashery

Comment: I'm not sure but most probably its an bug that happens after updating the iOS. and also just check and verify the  system language settings on the device/simulator.  can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006782/english-letters-is-in-reverse-orderinside-wkwebview-for-arabic-app may be this question helps you @iosDev